# OAuth authorization - Establishing a requestToken

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I need to get request token to be able to work with LinkedIn API.

I'm trying to send this request (by POST) to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
```

with those parameters

```
'oauth_callback' => 'http://www.myserver.com/tokenReturned',
'oauth_consumer_key' => '---',
'oauth_consumer_secret' => '---',
'oauth_nonce' => uniqid(time(), TRUE),
'oauth_signature_method' => 'PLAINTEXT',
'oauth_signature' => '---',
'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
'oauth_version' => '1.0'
```

Anyway, the LinkedIn server is responding HTTP 100 and this message:

```
oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_signature_method&oauth_signature&oauth_timestamp&oauth_nonce
```

What am i doing wrong? Which parameter am i missing?

Or should parameters be send via HTTP Header, not through POST parameters?

Comment: You aren't intended to send `consumer_secret`. Apart from that everything looks allright... Could you post full code how you're sending this? Maybe there is a mistake in generating signature or something else...

Comment: Try sending it with header though. Their documentation doesn't provide any certain examples, but normally people send `oauth_*` values in `Authorization` header.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters should be sent in the "Authorization" HTTP header.  For example:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a2161%2flogin%2flinkedin", oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_KEY", oauth_nonce="SOME_NOUNCE", oauth_signature="YOUR_SIGNATURE", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="YOUR_TIMESTAMP", oauth_version="1.0"
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Note a few things:

- You should never send your oauth consumer secret
- the callback url needs to be encoded

More info available here: http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1245